# R: Adding YoY Growth column in long dataframe with many variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with each observation representing a SKU at a point in time with characteristics of the SKU along with a yearmon zoo variable as well as its price at that point in time. I am trying to figure out a way to add a column to my dataframe that would calculate the year over year growth in the price for each SKU. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: I'm trying to answer this question, but it's important to know the structure of your data. Do you have a value for every month of the year for every SKU number? If so, you could use a `dplyr` window function. It gets more complicated if the frequency of the data is inconsistent. The `dplyr` window function vignette is worth reading in either case:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html